# ifelse statement - add a variable based on a condition

Tags: r, variables, if-statement, addition

I am trying to add a factor variable "Economy" with levels "Developed" and "Developing" to my dataset that has a list of countries.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Developed <- data.frame(c("Andorra", "Faroe Islands", "Ireland", "Monaco", "Spain", "Australia", "Finland",
           "Israel", "Netherlands", "Sweden", "Austria", "France", "Italy", "New Zealand", "Switzerland", 
           "Belgium", "Germany", "Japan", "Norway", "Turkey", "Bermuda", "Greece", "Liechtenstein", 
           "Portugal", "United Kingdom", "Canada", "Holy See", "Luxembourg", "San Marino", "United States",
           "Denmark", "Iceland", "Malta", "South Africa", "Hong Kong", "South Korea", "Singapore", "Taiwan"))
names(Developed) <- "Country"

total$Economy <- ifelse(d$Country==Developed$Country, "Developed", "Developing")
```

It produces the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(data$Country, Developed$Country) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: what is the `d` here? please make the code reproducible.

Comment: It's telling you that you have more countries in `d` than in `Developped`.  It will throw this error if the length don't match when you use `==`. Try `ifelse(d$Country%in%Developed$Country, "Developed", "Developing")` instead

Answer (score 0):

@DJJ,

```
ifelse(d$Country%in%Developed$Country, "Developed", "Developing")
```

worked perfectly! Problem solved.